# Display react.js component names in UI?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

**Problem**: The naming of components in our react web app is getting a bit inconsistent. This is because of the natural growth of the project (code and UI design became inconsistent). Before I rename components, I would like to communicate the current names with our designers and agree on a common wording.

**Searched Solution**: I am looking for a way to display in the browser the name of each component. I want to avoid touching the code of each component in order to realise this. I would then take a screenshot and use it for the conversation with design.

Comment: if its a class component you can use `this.constructor.name`

Comment: Thanks @Sagivb.g for your answer. I specified the question a bit. I want to avoid touching the code of each component. I am hoping for a plugin or library that helps me to do this.

Comment: Other than scanning all files for component definition I think you can't know the names of all the component you have in your project unless you write some code in each component file to store all the names of each component somewhere may be in global window...

In your router however you may get the component name by `<component>.type.displayName`

Comment: You could try the react devtools. They don't display the name on the screen but show the component tree. You can then use the selector to highlight the component in the tree or vice versa select a component in the tree and see how they are rendered. This might be enough for your use case :)

Comment: Yeah, this is a good hint. The component tree from the react devtools is what I am pretty much looking for. Only displayed at once for all components.